# How to install Papyrus on eclipse-CDT without update site ?

Tags: eclipse, uml, eclipse-cdt, papyrus

Where can I download all the plugins required to run Papyrus on eclipse CDT as zipped files and without to use eclipse itself ?

I am using eclipse CDT 4.5.2 to develop embedded C applications and I would like to add the Papyrus modeling tools so I can view and draw UML models in the same eclipse instance. I am looking for a way to achieve this on this eclipse CDT installation, not to start from the Papyrus distribution except if there is no other way.

The main constraint is that I cannot use any update site [long story short : company network] from eclipse, therefore I use to install the other plugins from a zipped archive containing jars. I couldn't find how to do the same thing with Papyrus and the UML tools.

Comment: https://www.eclipse.org/papyrus/downloads/index.php

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This site allows me to download the update site of Papyrus, anyway it seems that I need a whole environment to install it because the installation fails (Missing requirement: Papyrus Backbone 1.1.4.201602101200 (org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.core 1.1.4.201602101200) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.emf.transaction 1.4.0' but it could not be found).
I couldn't find a list of all the update-site I need. Is it a bad idea to add Papyrus to an existing eclipse-CDT build ?

Comment: Note that I already installed the EMF-XSD package. I tried to install MDTUML2 and UML2Tools but the installation fails :  Software being installed: UML2 Tools (Incubation) 0.9.0.v200906190654 (org.eclipse.uml2tools.feature.group 0.9.0.v200906190654)
  Missing requirement: Sequence Diagram Plugin (Incubation) 0.9.0.v200906190654 (org.eclipse.uml2.diagram.sequence 0.9.0.v200906190654) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.ocl.ecore 0.0.0' but it could not be found

Comment: It sounds like the papyrus installation is depending on other eclipse components. You may have more luck getting an answer by visiting the [forum for papyrus](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=thread&frm_id=121) to track down all the parts you need offline.

Comment: I already did and I am probably going to try to install everything from another network. Anyway too bad there's not a package with all what is necessary except the core of eclipse itself.